# Using data validation to get a value within a formula

Tags: excel, validation

I'm trying to make a costing spreadsheet for a friend, and I'm trying to make it as user friendly as possible... In doing this I would ideally like to not use any helper columns, so I'm trying to get everything into one formula.

So, on the enquiry sheet, my friend would select options from a number of dropdown boxes. Let's use colour as a simple example. Red is £5/m^2, Blue is £10/m^ and Yellow is £20/m^2.

What I want is for the formula to see "Okay, they've selected Blue, so I'm going to times the Length by the Width times the value for Blue" and to be able to go to the data sheet, pull the value for Blue (10) and then do it's business.

If it were this simple, I'd probably just use some nested if statements, but there are loads of different variables and that's not the only computation needing to be done.

Is it possible to do this without helper cells?

Thank you in advance (and sorry for personifying excel!)

T

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `Excel formula to get cell color`